# Implementing Idempotency-key for a POST method in Springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, post, caching, idempotent

I want to implement idempotency-key for POST method in springboot.

eg: http://localhost:8020/project/createStudent

Above is my POST method invocation. I will pass student details in body along with idempotency-key in header.

What I want to achieve is that when the request is sent, then  the idempotency-key and api response must be stored in a key cache only on successful creation of record. On subsequent POST requests made with same data, the cache should be verified against the idempotency-key for duplicates. And if the key is found then just send Conflict(409) response.
I know how to send an idempotency key in header and I also know that we could use @Cacheable in springboot to cache the response. But, I haven't found a solution to below

1. How to implement @Cachable to store the cache based on idempotency key sent from client. (Every distinct record will have a new idempotency-key)
2. How to verify if a response object/record is present in cache by passing an idempotency-key.

There are many solution on the internet but they don't talk about saving and retrieving cache based on idempotency-key. They just ask to define a method with @Cacheable and rest will happen automatically.

Comment: Did you implement for idempotency?